# why doesn't dart support declared exceptions

Tags: dart

what is the motivation behind not-allowing **exception declaration** in method/function signatures in dart? wouldn't it be better to allow programmers to declare exceptions in method signatures and then check that these exceptions are either propagated or caught (with a **catch** block) in **checked mode** (kinda like in java)? i'm sure the designers of dart have good reasons for their decisions, and it would be great if they could enlighten the users of dart with this information.

UPDATE: i've read a lot of the articles on dartlang.org and it seems that there is a very precise, clear-cut reason for nearly every design decision in dart. so i believe there is a correct answer to this question and thus it should not create debate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is unique in its rigorous treatment of exceptions. (C++ has something similar, but it's optional, and it works differently.)

Python, Javascript, and even Java-based Scala and Groovy don't subscribe to this treatment of exception types.

Basically, it adds boilerplate for little gained. In practice, the majority of exceptions are out-of-bounds, null pointer, etc. (This is particularly true in a browser, where file I/O and other errors are less common.) These exceptions can happen almost anywhere.

Comment: While I agree with this answer, and it's that Dart designers didn't want exceptions used as a form of flow control, note that exceptions and errors in Dart are different. Exceptions are designed to be caught and almost like "errors a dev can expect" and errors like npe's should not, and should halt program execution.

Comment: @MattB, yes this division between "errors" and "exceptions" is very much like Java's. This distinction is not present in many other languages. I used the two interchangeably in my answer. I will edit it.